# How can I cleanup the solution?

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

I'm trying to create Entity Data Model using Visual Studio 2012 and Oracle 10g.
I keep getting this error:

```
   Error    1   Error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Decimal[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=32,Scale=0]' of member 'SEC_ID' in type 'Model.SEC' is not compatible with 'OracleEFProvider.number[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=10,Scale=0]' of member 'QUARTAL_SEC_ID' in type 'Model.Store.QUARTAL'.
```

I have tried to remove the model and generate it from the scratch more times. I haven't imported the associations. I have also cleaned up the solution more times. visual Studio see the association no matter what I do.

Indeed sec_id has number(32) and quartal_sec_id - number(10) in the database. I can't change it there. I wish to fix it in VS. I wish that VS not imports associations when I chose this option.  I have changed both types in mapping details in VS12 to int32. But it doesn't help.